# Two elements in one line with stretching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to keep a textarea and a button in one line while having the textarea extend horizontally as much as possible:

```
        <div class="col-md-10 form-inline">
            <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button>small button</button>
        </div>
```

The "form-inline" class on the col makes both in one line, however, it shrinks the textarea. If I remove "form-inline", then the textarea stretches 100% - but the button appears in the next line.

Is it possible to have both in one line with a wide textarea?

Comment: make button relative to textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
.form-inline { position: relative; padding-right: 160px; }
.form-inline > textarea { width: 100%; }
.form-inline > button { width: 150px; height: 35px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Check [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ravk/y19jczbg/) here.

Comment: That looks perfect, I'll give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

set width for textarea in percentage

```
<div class="col-md-10 form-inline">
 <textarea class="form-control" style="width:90%"></textarea>
 <button>small button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that would be one option. However, since the button has a fixed width, this would not always add up to 100% width.

Answer (score -1):

```
   .form-control{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
    }
```